# How to read the two columns of data in this text file?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, average

I have a text file which include some numbers and words as shown below.

How to read first column and second column?

After reading the file, I need to get an average value of the first column.

```
33512 test1
3312  test2
551   test3
33    test4
5     test5
```

Comment: Numbers and words are written in line. First line has 33512 test1 / second line has 3312 test2 ....

Comment: Show what you tried as properly formatted code in the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
vals = []

with open('filename.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        vals.append(line.split()[0:2])

numbers = [val[0] for val in vals]
avg = sum(numbers) / len(numbers)
```

Comment: You forgot to turn the number strings into `int`s…